Modeling for categorical data
I am trying to develop a KMeans model for my categorical dataset. The problem here is that all the instances in the dataset are categorical. I have tried One hot Encoding and Label Encoder. I am unable to convert all my columns to numerical values. I can only convert one column into a numerical set. Upon using label encoder it generated null values.
Is there a way to implement an ML model for this kind of dataset?
I have tried using One hot Encoder and label encoder to convert the columns into numerical datasets. I need to convert all my columns to numerical datasets.
